# I declared a variable for a class, and passed it into a method to instantiate it, but the original variable remains uninstantiated

Tags: c#, function, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I know that classes are ALWAYS passed by reference differently from structs that are passed by value.

If you take a look at the following code you can see that I call a function with no `ref` keyword (supposedly there's no need for it since `Path` is a class and therefore it should be always automatically called by ref with no need for the `ref` keyword).

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();      
    Func(myPath);

    if (myPath == null)
       MessageBox.Show("AAAARGH");
}

Path myPath;

private void Func(Path p)
{
    if (p == null)
        p = new Path();
}
```

So after the function call, I'd expect `myPath` not to be `null` anymore since it has been initialized in `Func()` but that's not true.

I'm working on a global value. Is that changing something?

Comment: Passing by reference you still cannot change where that reference is pointing to without the ref keyword. You can modify the properties of that object, but you can't make a new object and have it persist back to the caller.

Comment: this is really bad design. Why not just use `myPath` directly? Also, whatever you're doing, it doesn't belong in code behind. Create a proper ViewModel.

Comment: I'm working on a multipath canvas. The same function can operate both on new paths and on paths selected by the user through mouse. This is why I have a myPath which stands for mouseSelectedPath. That said you'r right I'll re-elaborate my code trying not to use a global path.    One more thing: why not working on code-behind? It's a quite complex program so I can't put everything in the xaml file.

Comment: Wrong. *Everything* (regardless of type) is pass-by-value if the parameter doesn't have `ref` or `out`. And *everything* (regardless of type) is pass-by-reference if the parameter has `ref` or `out`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initially call `Func()`, `myPath` and `p` reference the same instance of `Path`. However, `myPath` and `p` remain two separate references, which happen to point to that same instance.

That is, until the following code runs:

```
p = new Path();
```

After that, `p` references a new instance of `Path` that is separate from the original. Changing properties in the instance that `p` refers to will not be reflected in the instance that `myPath` refers to.

In other words:

```
private void Func(Path p)  // p is a separate reference, referencing same Path as myPath
{
    if (p == null)         // p still references same Path as myPath
        p = new Path();    // now p references a new instance of Path, separate from myPath
}
```

You can use the `ref` (or `out`) keyword so that the reference identified by `myPath` is itself passed "by reference", the effect of which is that `myPath` and `p` are a single reference.

Then when you create a new instance of `Path` inside your method, `myPath` and `p` remain a single reference, both pointing to the new instance. (Your original instance is still out there in memory somewhere, but nothing is referencing it anymore.)

```
Path myPath = null;

private void Func(ref Path p)  // p is same reference as myPath
{
    if (p == null)
        p = new Path();        // p and myPath are still same reference,
                               //   now referencing a new instance of Path
}
```

Or:

```
Path myPath;

private void Func(out Path p)  // p is same reference as myPath
{
    if (p == null)     
        p = new Path();        // p and myPath are still same reference,
                               //   now referencing a new instance of Path
}
```

Comment: Wrong. "An instance of a class" is not a value in C# and cannot be "passed". When you create an instance, you get a *reference* (a value of a reference type), and you can only manipulate instances through these *references*. These references can be passed by value (without `ref` or `out`) or by reference (with `ref` or `out`).

Answer (score 1):

You have to mark the Parameter with 'out'.

For more Information about 'out' look at this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx

Comment: In the described scenario the use of 'out' is favorable over 'ref' as it gives a clearer message of the intent of the method call. Once again, the most precise answer doesn't get the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a value by reference is very different from using `ref` keyword. Translating this to C or C++ terms:

- passing an object is like passing a pointer
- passing an object with
  `ref` is like passing a pointer to pointer.

If you want to change value of your variable inside function, you need to use `ref` or `out`.

Comment: Passing by reference is *exactly* using the `ref` keyword.